# How to set Security.sandboxType through programming in Flex

Tags: apache-flex, flex4

I need to call JavaScript for that I need to set

flash.system.Security.sandboxType as LOCAL_TRUSTED. Default value is LOCAL_WITH_NETWORK.

I can change this setting by Global setting of Flash player.

Question is how can I set it throguh coding so that my application work on every local system ?

Answer (score 0):

Hmm,

From what I understand, you want your user to launch a swf from their filesystem and access javascript functions. 
If it's the case, the answer is simple, you can't. It would be a serious security hole.

Comment: Thanks for response. I can do it manually by changing global setting at http://www.macromedia.com/support/documentation/en/flashplayer/help/settings_manager04.html. We can run javascript by adding the folder containing javascript as trusted location. I want to do it through coding so that wherever my application run it can access javascript.

Comment: I see but, as said above, you won't be able to do it.

Flash determines itself if a swf is local trusted by looking at the settings manager or the configuration file.